# Set a session variables using twig

Tags: php, twig, php-5.3, php-5.4, twig-extension

I have a question. I have a route on my site where I put in session an variable like this:

```
 public function userCaptcha(){
    $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 0;
 }
```

Now I have another route witch render a view :

```
public function index(){
    $this->session = $_SESSION;
    return $this->render('template/index.twig');
}
```

In the index template I do :

```
 {{ dump(session.isFacebookRegistration) }}
 {% set session = session|merge({'isFacebookRegistration' : 3}) %}
```

I access the first route : userCaptcha() one time but the route index() 2 times, normally I need to see the first time 0 and the second 3. But I see only the 0 for 2 times. Can you help me please? The idea is to show for first time 0 for the rest 3. Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a PHP var on Twig side. Every time your view is reloaded, changes you made to your variable will be lost. You can try something like this:

```
public function userCaptcha(){
    $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 0;
}

public function index(){
    if (isset($_SESSION['flag'])) {
        $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 3;
    }
    $_SESSION['flag'] = true;
    $this->session = $_SESSION;
    return $this->render('template/index.twig');
}
```

This way, executing index() for first time won't change `isFacebookRegistration` value, but will set a flag. Next time, the conditial will be true an `isFacebookRegistration` will change.